# python sqlite: find matching rows from two tables and output columns

Tags: python, sqlite

I have one sqlite database with two tables 'NNDATA' and 'TEAM'.  TEAM has one column 'cpids'.  NNDATA has 8 columns, column[0] is 'CPID' some but not all of which will match cpids from TEAM table.

where cpids from TEAM match CPID from NNDATA, I want to return the matched row entries from column[2] 'NeuralMagnitude' and column[5] 'Address' from NNDATA

I tried:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("Rain.db")
c = conn.cursor()
address = c.execute('select Address from NNDATA where CPID=(select cpids from TEAM)').fetchall()
nn_mag = c.execute('select NeuralMagnitude from NNDATA where CPID=(select cpids from TEAM)').fetchall()
conn.close()
```

but it just gives me one result, I did a list compare and got 100s of matches, so Im 99% sure its not finding all the matches.

I also tried making cpids a variable:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("Rain.db")
c = conn.cursor()
cpids = c.execute('select cpids from TEAM').fetchall()
address = c.execute('select Address from NNDATA where CPID={cpids}'.format(cpids=cpids)).fetchall()
nn_mag = c.execute('select NeuralMagnitude from NNDATA where CPID={cpids}'.format(cpids=cpids)).fetchall()
conn.close()
```

but that seemed to say Address and NeuralMagnitude were not recognised.

I saw some sqlite solutions but they seemed to run to several lines of code, and I think for Python it has to be called in a single line?
Thanks.

Comment: if you search for multiple values like in your id case you need to do WHERE cpid IN (1,2,3,4) ... https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/in.php

Comment: Ok that makes sense, will try it tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@snow was correct, thanks:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("Rain.db")
c = conn.cursor()
address = c.execute('select Address from NNDATA where CPID in (select cpids from TEAM)').fetchall()
nn_mag = c.execute('select NeuralMagnitude from NNDATA where CPID in (select cpids from TEAM)').fetchall()
conn.close()
```